# C Program Problem

Tags: programming

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int a;
int count=0;

for(a=1;a<=10;a=a+1)
     {
     if(a>3)
         count=count+1;
     }
 printf("%d numbers were greater than 3\n",count);

 return 0;
}
```

why have the error of 
ERROR: variable 'file name' not defined
ERROR: command 'file name' not found
ERROR: cannot execute program 'file name'

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the **commands** you are using to compile and run the program.

Answer (score 2):

In Unix, the executable programs aren't searched for in the current directory, to avoid security risks due to inadvertently running the wrong program.

You have to do e.g.

```
cc pgm.c -o pgm
./pgm
```

to run your program (`./` specifically asks to run the executable in the current directory, it doesn't rely on the shell searching for a program called `pgm`).